# vb net append list of with list of item/index

Tags: vb.net, variables, indexoutofrangeexception, outofrangeexception, listof

I have a custom control object called **cc1**.
I store cc1 like this `Public cc1List As New List(Of cc1)` and add stuff to it, works like a charm.

Now i want to remove some item inside it, with a known index, so i create `Dim cc1ListTemp As New List(Of cc1)`, loop through the whole index of cc1, and append all items excluding the removed index through this Code: `cc1ListTemp.Add(cc1List(i))` but it keeps on throwing an OutOfRangeException, beginning with the first loop (i = 0) all the way up.

But i know for sure that `cc1List(i)` where i = 0 to 5 is fully populated, and checked even in runtime before triggering the exception (i can fully access/edit/call cc1List(0)).

Do i need to append in a different way?
If needed i can provide more code.

Edit0:

```
        Dim cc1ListTemp As New List(Of cc1)
        For i = 0 To CWBListMaxIndex
            If Not i = IndexToRemove Then
                cc1ListTemp.Add(cc1List(i))
            End If
        Next
        cc1List = cc1ListTemp
```

Adding works fine, mixed add/append.

```
cc1List.Append(cc1TempObject)
cc1List.Add(cc1TempObject)
```

Edit1: reproduced it with Textboxes replacing cc1 inside a new project.

Comment: I don't see an issue with what you've shown so far.

Comment: Post the full code of the issue.

Comment: `CWBListMaxIndex` is maybe out of sync?  Try `cc1List.Count - 1` instead.

Comment: @LarsTech CWBListMaxIndex is defined publicly, and incremented by 1 each time the list is added/appended, guaranteed. Also the error is thrown on first loop, while i = 0, just like on second loop where i = 1, i outputted i just before exception is thrown already.       Edit0: i tried hardcoding i anyway, set to 1, filled cc1List 5 times with "add" call, still same error. :/

Comment: You are talking about code we can't see.  You have to post the code that can reproduce the exception for us.

Comment: Why not just use the List Remove methods? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=net-5.0

Comment: @1lsvks5w2l you don't need a public variable for the count. Just use cc1List.Count - 1

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what index you want to remove, use the `RemoveAt` method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of TextBox) From {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4}
    Dim IndexToRemove = 1
    lst.RemoveAt(IndexToRemove)
    For Each TB In lst
        Debug.Print(TB.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Prints

```
TextBox1
TextBox3
TextBox4
```

in the Immediate Window